# Ask for password when opening Database - LotusNotes/DominoDesigner

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

My task is, when opening a database in Lotus Notes, the current user will be ask to input his/her password that was given by his superior. Is there a way how to do that? Just a simple prompt or form that will ask for your password before viewing the database.

Answer (score 3):

Please understand that I do not intend this answer to be disrespectful, but this is really not a task for a beginner at Notes and Domino, as you have stated that you are. You should tell that to your boss. This is a task for someone who has deep understanding of the principles of security and of the mechanisms Notes and Domino provide for it. If you do not understand my comments on @Thomas Adrian's answer, then that applies to you. Again, no disrespect intended.

As security guru Bruce Schneier said, "if you ask amateurs to act as front-line security personnel, you shouldn't be surprised when you get amateur security".

Comment: When someone logs in into Notes, you can safely assume that person is who he/she is (authentication). More proof is useless. Some explanation: it can be done easily using standard Notes security, using groups or roles. If access to the database is to be limited to specific people, put their names in a group and add the group to the ACL of the database. Ask your Administrator, he/she should know exactly what to do.

Comment: That's true, but only if users do not share workstations and always lock their workstations whenever they are away. Usually when I have heard requests for password prompts on applications, it's been because of that. I.e., as an additional layer on top of ACL security. OTOH, I agree that generating a password prompt in application code is a poor substitute for proper security policy enforcement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put code in queryopendatabase which is located in database script.

1. Create a button for your superior to store the password in a general profile document within the database

2 when users open the database use the queryopendatabase script to present a password prompt. You can use inputbox in lotus script. Verify the password against the profile document. If a wrong password is entered close the database.

You can use the following code as an embryo, This code use a "real" document but you can easily modify this to be a profile document.

Remember when you test this to close Domino Designer as the NSF is cached as long as DDE is open

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidatabase)

    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Set db = source.Database
    Dim d As NotesDocument, flag As Integer, upw As String, pw As String
    upw = InputBox("Enter Password")

    Set d = db.getView("Main").getFirstDocument()
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        pw = d.password(0)
        If pw = upw Then
            flag = 1
        End If

    End If
    If flag <> 1 Then Call source.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Okay. I can do that.

2. I'm new to Domino Designer. Just want to know, is there any tutorial how to do that? Because I'm still confused on what's what in DominoDesigner. Thanks btw

Comment: Thomas has described this such that the password is the same for all users, Is that what your boss wants?

Comment: Also, you need to understand that this type of solution adds very little to the actual security of your application. As described above, the password is actually not protected at all. Anyone who knows where it is can read it, and it's not hard for a knowledgeable user to find where it is. There are ways to address that by using the @Password function to store a hash of the password and changing the comparison code to check the hash instead of directly matching pw = upw. And if using individual per-user passwords, you can user Reader Names field protection to hide passwords from other users.

Comment: You know, that an "Inputbox" shows the password you are typing... do you?

Comment: ok you made your point. It is not very secure. I get it. Feel welcome to provide a better answer.